# Making Metro tile appear in the first view

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a shortcut which I am using to create a metro tile in Windows 8. When I place the shortcut in `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, the tile appears at the very end where I need to scroll to see it. Is there a way to control ordering so that it always appears in the first screen?

Comment: I hope not; in Raymond Chen's words, imagine if everyone did this.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. One of the fundamental themes of Windows 8 is that the user is in charge, so in general, any thing that that a developer might do in their application that would override or disrupt the user's control of their experience isn't allowed.  The user can, of course, move the tile wherever he or she wants once it's on the start screen.