# How to place a tile on the windows 8 start screen programmatically?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am building a windows store app. I want the tile of that app at a specific location of my start screen. Is there any API to code the position of my tile on start screen?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use program to control the tile position of Windows 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504866/how-to-use-program-to-control-the-tile-position-of-windows-8)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making Metro tile appear in the first view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153716/making-metro-tile-appear-in-the-first-view)

Answer (score 4):

No.  You can't control where the tile goes - that is up to the user to determine.  The central pillar of the Windows 8 environment design philosophy is that the user is in control.

Comment: But why can other programs **do** this? f.e. [Flexera Adminstudio](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/adminstudio.htm). There you can build a package and set up the position where the Tile has to be added in the start menu.

Comment: @Martin - What you are talking about there is not a Windows Store App.  I dare say (without reading too much of the linked page) that this uses manipulations *outside the app* to achieve the effect.

Comment: @ZombieSheep Yes you are right, this is not a Windows Store App. But the question is: "how can i place my app tile at the definied position (programmatically)" means if I understand you in the right way there must be a possibility because if they are successful in placing an app, there **must** be a way to do manipulation (programmatically) maybe not from the app but from *full* .net or others.

Comment: @Martin - There must be a way, you are correct, but the APIs available in the Windows Store framework do not allow for it, and it is not unreasonable to infer this as being part of the OPs question.  If you rely on external code you may not be able to even run that code (e.g. on an RT device).  You can't even hack around it with the framework due to the Windows Store's submission and validation processes.

Comment: @ZombieSheep - Ok. So I think there must be two questions: *1. Can the Windows Store Framework pin tiles?* - No! --- *2. What is the way to pin tiles to the correct position?* - Thats also my problem and i can not find any good solutions (researched google, stackexchange...)

Comment: @Martin - probably best to start your own question, but to answer your two questions... 1) Yes, it CAN pin tiles.  2) define "correct position".  In MS's view "correct position" pretty much means "where the user wants to put it".  If it were any other way, every app that got installed could try to put is tile first in the list and make the user's choice of tile preferences go out the window.

Comment: @ZombieSheep - I know the MS view, but I also know my clients view. And in enterprise environments you have mostly the case that there should no or less user choice.

Comment: In an enterprise scenario, you are likely to have more leeway with this, as you described.  The app itself will have no control over tile positioning, but you may be able to re-order your tiles from an external assembly. Sadly, though, this bring us back to your initial question of how to do it. I don't know, but I do suggest starting a new question as this is not the place to discuss this.

Comment: @ZombieSheep - [Asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364257/pin-tile-to-selected-position-on-startscreen-programmatically-windows-8) ;)