# How to programmatically pin a site to start screen in windows 8

Tags: c#, javascript, windows, internet-explorer, vbscript

Is there a way to pin a web site to start screen in IE 10 using code?

I can see shortcuts created for pinned sites in "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Application Shortcuts". However, I can't figure out where Windows stores pinned site data. If I simply create a shortcut and drop it in that folder it doesn't work.

For coding I prefer C#, but javascript or vbscript should be fine.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? This is going to piss a lot of people off unless 1) Your client has specifically asked for this, or 2) It's just for your personal use. I like the idea as a developer, but as a user I would throw my computer out the window if sites started putting junk on my taskbar. As for the how, I'm not really sure. Maybe there is an event that gets triggered so that Windows knows that the _user_ pinned it? I don't think there is a way around it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to place a tile on the windows 8 start screen programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994978/how-to-place-a-tile-on-the-windows-8-start-screen-programmatically)

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. Code would be run by the user, not initiated from a web site he visits. Also I need to pin to start screen, not the taskbar. Main reason for this is custom deployment of the Window 8 OS. Client needs scripted installs AND pinned corporate intranet URLs on the start screen. I need to do this as part of unattended install. You get the idea I suppose.

Comment: I also know about those utilities out there, like ObliTile. But still I'd like to do this "manually", instead of relying on a "shareware" grade app, which my client might object to.

Comment: @Ramesh, thanks for the link, but that questions is not actually the same. Here's I'm asking about IE pinned sites specifically, and I'm not concerned where the tile is placed in the start screen at all.

Answer (score 2):

The [Customize the Start Screen](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134269.aspx) article on TechNet shows how to put a custom Start screen layout in your deployment. Windows 8.1 adds a [Start screen layout policy](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2013/06/customising-windows-8-1-start-screen-layout-with-group-policy/) you can use as well. Deployment issues are better-suited to ServerFault, not StackOverflow.